Window Functions yield different results when using views
Considering the following schema (and sample data)
CREATE TABLE sample
(
    adjustment_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    balance_id    BIGINT  NOT NULL,
    operation_id  BIGINT  NOT NULL,
    phase         TINYINT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO sample(balance_id, operation_id, phase)
VALUES (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 3, 1);

CREATE VIEW v_sample AS
SELECT *
FROM sample;


The following code yields this result:
SELECT *,
       rank() OVER w             AS `rank`,
       first_value(phase) OVER w AS `latest_phase`
FROM sample
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY balance_id, operation_id ORDER BY adjustment_id DESC);




adjustment_id
balance_id
operation_id
phase
rank
latest_phase




3
1
1
3
1
3


2
1
1
2
2
3


1
1
1
1
3
3


5
1
2
2
1
2


4
1
2
1
2
2


6
1
3
1
1
1



However, the same query (but using views) yields completely different results:
SELECT *,
       rank() OVER w             AS `rank`,
       first_value(phase) OVER w AS `latest_phase`
FROM v_sample
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY balance_id, operation_id ORDER BY adjustment_id DESC);




adjustment_id
balance_id
operation_id
phase
rank
latest_phase




3
1
1
3
1
3


2
1
1
2
2
3


1
1
1
1
3
3


5
1
2
2
4
3


4
1
2
1
5
3


6
1
3
1
6
3




I fail to understand why. What am I missing? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Cannot reproduce. fiddle

Thanks to the prompt comments (thanks @Akina !), I can confirm this issue is only replicable in mysql/mysql-service:8.0.26-1.2.4. Upgrading to a more recent version resolved this issue.
Thank you.
